# How to protect objects from autorelease?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory, autorelease

Finally the objective-c memory management caught me. I'm fighting with a problem now for 2 days. I´m new to Objective C and can't solve the problem by my own.
Seems like I am unknowingly overreleasing an Object.
If I´m doin the zombie analysis I´m getting the "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object.."

This is the important part of the Analysis Log I guess: 
The last line with RefCt -1 shows the responsible caller is -[XClass dataset]

dataset is a NSDictionary that I use to store data of every object.
Im Using the Dictionary in two extern classes by using the 2 methods
of XClass ("updateDictionary:" and "dict:")

The Declaration of the File:

```
XClass.h:  
...  
NSDictionary* dataset;    
...  
@property (retain) NSDictionary *dataset;  
- (id)initWithDeviceValue:(NSDictionary*)DataSet  
- (void) updateDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)dict;
```

```
XClass.m:

@synthesize dataset;  

-(id)initWithDeviceValue:(NSDictionary*)DataSet{  
..  
if (self = [super init])  
{  
      dataset = DataSet;}  
}  
return self;  
}    
- (void) updateDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{  
    dataset=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];  
}  

-(NSDictionary *)dict{  
    return dataset;  
}
```

The first extern method calling the (dict:) function gets the actual dictionary correctly.
The second function doesn't get the dictionary because it seems to be released!

Like I said the last line of the zombie log is:

> Malloc: Zombie 
>   RefCt: -1  Responsible caller is -[XClass dataset]

The former interesting lines:

Line 2 of the Zombielog:

> Malloc:CFRetain   RefCt:2   Responsible Caller:-[XClass dataset]

Line 3 of the Zombielog:

> Malloc:Autorelease   RefCt:empty   Responsible Caller:-[XClass
>   dataset]

It seems like the dictionary of my object got autoreleased. Maybe because it had the RefCt (retain count?) of 2 which was too much and so got autoreleased?
How can I prevent objects from being autoreleased?

Comment: The problem is because you need to use self.dataset to have it retained properly. Look at pawan.mangal's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XClass.m:
try this ...

```
@synthesize dataset;  

-(id)initWithDeviceValue:(NSDictionary*)DataSet{  
    ..  
    if (self = [super init])  
    {  
          self.dataset = DataSet;
    }  
    return self;  
}    
- (void) updateDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{  
    self.dataset=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];  
}  

-(NSDictionary *)dict{  
    return dataset;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, it makes sense for me but Im getting the next error now when I write self.dataset: EventType:Zombie , RefCt -1, Responsible Library: GraphicsServices, Responsible Caller GSEventRunModal. What can I do with GSEventRunModal?

Comment: I get the following error now: -[XClass setDataset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6044820. I dont have a setDataset function in my class. How to handle this error? Thanks for help

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *dataset;   create property means it create accessor method for that variable (get and set method), if u synthesize in .m file .better if u share whole code. or go through the apple documentation for @property .

Comment: Thanks. Yes , now I know where the setDataset method comes from, its the generated one from the property

Answer (score 0):

@pawan.mangal
Problem solved! It´s all about the good old retainCount. When I initialize the new Objects from Xclass I have to add a retain like `[code][[XClass objectx]retain][/code]` in order to keep it alive for more than one request.
Also I deleted both methods from the class and let the synchronised getters and setters do the work.
The retainCount of the object decreases by 1 every time I´m using its automatically generated accessor (the getter in this case) . Right?

Comment: @Fabian- great to watch u solved the issue.for me  at earlier stage to get familiar with property and memory management took two months  .....